# Hide scroll bars on IE (retain border)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a div with:

```
overflow-y: scroll
```

I wish to hide the scroll bar on IE, I use:

```
-ms-overflow-style: none;
```

Unfortunately this removes the border on the div:

```
border-right: 1px solid red;
```

How can I remove scroll bars in IE but still retain a border on the div?

Comment: That's weird, do you care if it only shows while they're scrolling and try something like `-ms-autohiding-scrollbar`?

Comment: I need it to be hidden on the div I am afraid.

Comment: I suppose if nothing else you could embed another div without the declaration to retain your border. Would tinker if I had time. +1

Answer (score 0):

With this code I am unable to replicate your problem in ie 11 or edge

```
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sit at sonet theophrastus, volumus 
torquatos at sit, te mucius detraxit nec. Eros impedit sadipscing no est,
wisi perpetua interpretaris ne est. In nam natum audiam abhorreant, 
postea salutandi nam an, ne vim admodum repudiandae dissentiunt. Ea vix debet 
invenire, id dicat periculis pro, ne mazim mediocrem reprehendunt cum. Vel inermis cotidieque an.

Id pri exerci ponderum, assum disputationi in eos. Ne brute definitionem 
sit, cibo putent vocibus ius an. Vix autem ludus ceteros te, disputando 
appellantur no mea. Ut qui labitur adipisci, his maiorum suscipiantur 
necessitatibus at.

Eum vide mutat harum at. In vim utinam aperiam, vel te delenit recteque 
theophrastus. Et has principes splendide, euismod dolores accommodare his
 cu. Quidam labores facilisi sea ei, in qui dignissim persequeris. Ei pro 
inani aeterno volutpat, nam no malis aperiri. Vim legimus patrioque 
rationibus ex.

Ad vis commune salutatus. At ancillae pertinacia mel, ne odio purto 
albucius duo. Ut pri augue admodum, pro at dicam tritani. Cu iusto dicit 
copio

sae his, nec ea reque doming.</div>

div {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid Red;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dMbYqG